# Storing a string in another variable in C

Tags: c, string, function, palindrome

I am writing a program to check if the given string is a palindrome or not. I wrote a function to reverse the string but unable to store the reversed string in a different variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char stringPalindrome(char s[100], int i, int n){
    char reversed = "";

    for(i=n;i>=0;i--){
        reversed += s[i];
    }

    return reversed;
}

int main(){
    char s[100];
    int i,n;

    gets(s);

    n = strlen(s)-1;

    printf("%s", stringPalindrome(s,i,n));

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to store a string in another variable without using `pointers` or `malloc` or `calloc` since I am new to this language and I have lots to learn

Comment: Please check the compiler warnings for `char reversed = "";` Moreover in C you cannot concatenate a string with `reversed += s[i];` You must pass a buffer to your `stringPalindrome`, or allocate memory for it.

Comment: Yes, I know about the error. What can I do instead of concatenating the string with an empty string?

Comment: use an other `char[100]` to compute the reversed string, or reverse the input string itself

Comment: Copy the characters (in reversed sequence) to another buffer (in sequence) and terminate the string.

Comment: also why *stringPalindrome* receives *i* in argument ? and never use *gets*, use *fgets*

Comment: @WeatherVane could you elaborate?

Comment: @bruno i should have initialized int i in the function

Comment: Please revise the previous chapters of your book!

Comment: *i* must be a local var in *stringPalindrome*, not a param. *reversed* must be `char reversed[100]` and your loop copy in it the input string in reverse order

Comment: out of that it is not necessary to reverse a string to check if it is a palindrome, that way is expensive for nothing

Comment: @bruno I could compare s[i] and s[n-i]. But I wanted to know how I can store a string in another variable

Comment: the simple way is to use *strcpy*

Comment: A string is not just "a variable". It is an array of chars. So, for starters, the destination array should be able to contain the original string. In C you declare the array size, and you never do it for `reversed` (that you declared as a single char using an initializer suitable for an array: the compiler should scream at you)

Comment: @RavuriPraneeth I edited my answer to add 3 was to reverse the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal here is not to check if a string is a palindrome but to reverse a string.

There are several problems in your code

- `char reversed = "";` is wrong, *reversed* is a `char , not a` char*`nor a`const char *`
- `reversed += s[i];` does not appends `s[i]` as you expected
- the parameter *i* of *stringPalindrome* has no sense, *i* must be a local variable, not a parameter
- never use *gets*, if the input is longer than the receiving array the behavior is undefined
- `printf("%s", stringPalindrome(s,i,n));` as an undefined behavior because *stringPalindrome* returns a `char` rather than a string

The function *stringPalindrome* cannot store the reverse string in a local variable being an array of character then return that array whose has an undefined behavior. You can letting the input string unchanged :

- use a static local variable in *stringPalindrome*, but each call of the function modifies the string made by a previous call
- dynamically allocate the reverse string in the heap using *malloc* in *stringPalindrome*, in that case the caller has the responsibility to *free* the array when it stops to use it
- also receive the array memorizing to the reversed string in parameter, as an out parameter, in hat case it is the responsibility of the caller to give an array enough long to store the result

Out of that in C the function *strcat* allows to concatenate strings, but in your case you want to add *one* char so directly assign that character rather than to use an expensive call to *strcat* (also supposing both strings are null terminated)

---

Using a global variable, the function has to take care to not write out of its static array :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * stringPalindrome(const char * s, size_t n)
{
  static char reversed[100];
  size_t i;
  
  if (n > sizeof(reversed) - 1)
    n = sizeof(reversed) - 1;
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    reversed[i] = s[n - i - 1];
  reversed[i] = 0;
  
  return reversed;
}

int main()
{
  char s[100];
  
  if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL)
    puts(stringPalindrome(s, strlen(s) - 1));
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
azer ty

yt reza
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Using dynamic allocation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * stringPalindrome(const char * s, size_t n)
{
  char * reversed = malloc(n + 1);
  size_t i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    reversed[i] = s[n - i - 1];
  reversed[i] = 0;
  
  return reversed;
}

int main()
{
  char s[100];
  
  if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL) {
    char * r = stringPalindrome(s, strlen(s) - 1);
                         
    puts(r);
    free(r);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
azer ty

yt reza
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Managing the result in an output parameter :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * stringPalindrome(const char * s, char * reversed, size_t n)
{
  size_t i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    reversed[i] = s[n - i - 1];
  reversed[i] = 0;
  
  return reversed;
}

int main()
{
  char s[100];
  char r[100];
  
  if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL) {
    puts(stringPalindrome(s, r, strlen(s) - 1));
    puts(r);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
azer ty
yt reza
yt reza
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.

There is *no* string type in C. All we have are pointers to `char`s. And by convention the string runs from the given location up to the fist zero byte that follows. There is no way to escape that.

But in order to find out whether a string is a palindrome or not, you do not have to reverse if first. Just compare the first with the last character if they match continue with the second and second to last and so on. Until a pair does not match. If you run out of pairs to compare (when they meet in the middle) the string is a palindrome. That way you can sidestep the issue of creating a new string.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to loop over the string and compare start and end characters. Use `fgets()` which allows you to set the max length of the string, `gets()` has no check so it should be avoided.

```
  int palindrom()
  {
    char s[100];
    if (fgets(s,sizeof s,stdin) != NULL)
    {
      int len = strlen(s);
      if (s[len-1] == '\n') --len; // if string is 100 chars there is no \n
      for (char* p = s, *q = s + len - 1; p >= q; ++p,--q)
      {
        if (*p != *q) return 0; // look until difference
      }
      return 1; // palindrome
    }
    puts("no input");
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Warning, `p >= q` is wrong and must be replaced by `p < q`, else the function always returns 1 except if the read line is empty (just contains newline, or even no newline but managed through *fgets* return value). `p <= q` is valid too but it is useless to check a character is equal to itself. Out of that I think it is better to return for instance -1 in case of EOF to allow the caller to distinguish that case specifically, and to remove the *puts* without impact for the caller, and in fact to not receive the string in parameter seems strange, but this is only a personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

first of all great that you started with programming.
There are three little points in your code:

1. You are using `gets()` which is a dangerous for buffer overflow, so I used `fgets()` here. Does not matter if you do not know what that means, because that is something advanced, but if you want to know more about that, let me know.
2. In `printf()` you want to print a string (`%s`) but your function `stringPalindrome` does return a char instead of an array of chars. Therefore you obtained an error. I fixed this by declaring the function to be of type `const char*`. Also `char reversed = "";` defines an empty character, so in the for loop you are trying to append characters to an empty character and this gives you a memory error. I fixed this by using a second array of characters (r) like s and added him to the parameters of the function call.
3. Finally the for loop itself. This problem raised out of the second pa

   ```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    const char* stringPalindrome(char s[100], char r[100], int i, int p, int n){

        for(i=0;i<p;i++){
            r[i] = s[n];
            n--;
        }
        return r;
    }

    int main(){
        char s[100];
        char r[100];
        int i,n,p;

        fgets(s, 100, stdin);

        p = strlen(s);
        n = p-1;

        printf("%s", stringPalindrome(s,r,i,p,n));

        return 0;
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! But I am getting the wrong output. I am some other value. If input = `aba`, the output is `aba╕+`.